# Windows Azure SQL Connection String Not Working

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I created a azure web application and a web role (WebApi) project under it. This web project comes with implementations of OAuth2 security which by default users LocalDb for authentication.

I wanted to migrate this to use an Azure SQL table and so I went on the azure management portal and created an SQL database. I then took the ADO.NET connection string from the management portal and replaced the connection string in the web.config file.

My web app works when hosted locally but when published to azure I get the following error:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
```

I don't know why it's complaining about SqlExpress as I have changed it to point to an Azure Sql connection string.

Can anybody help?

EDIT: entityFramework section added!

```
  <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Comment: Can you have enable the firewall permission in azure SQL database  for accessing the data base?

Comment: Did you check if you have the correct provider name in your connection string (it should be `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`)? In addition, check your <entityFramework> section in web.config to point to the correct provider:  `<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />`

Comment: HI there, <entityFramework> section added above!.

Yes I have providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient" in the connection string. 

I have enabled the firewall permission in azure SQL. Does it take time for this to take effect?